# Equivalent number of looks (ENL) calculation

Tags: filters, noise, estimation

As stated in [gagnon1997speckle](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.54.3239&rep=rep1&type=pdf) in paragraph 2.2, under the unit-mean noise assumption one can say that:

\begin{equation}
ENL = \left(\frac{\bar{y}}{\sigma_{y}} \right)^2 = \frac{1}{\sigma_{n}^2}
\end{equation}

where
\begin{equation}
y = nx, \qquad \bar{y} = E[y]
\end{equation}

Can you help me to understand that assertion?

Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: What does $\bar{y}$ represent in this case?

Comment: $\bar{y}$ is the mean of the random array $y$, which is the observed signal; $x$ is a random array which represents the original signal and $n$ is multiplicative noise.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed that part.